# JSON string into specific category (PHP)

Tags: php

I want to add a new item(title, content, author) under "blogs" in JSON. But I'm new to this. I don't know how to improve that. My current progress is that it will create a new array rather than fill in the "blogs". This my PHP code

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //open the json file
        $data = file_get_contents('blog.json');
        $data = json_decode($data, true);
            
        //data in out POST
        $input = array(
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'content' => $_POST['content'],
            'author' => $_POST['author']
        );
            
        //append the input to our array
        $data[] = $input;
        //encode back to json
        $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        file_put_contents('blog.json', $data);
    }
?>
```

Here my JSON file

```json
{
    "blogs": 
    [
        {
          "title": "Tecnology is Essential",
          "content": "Why do we use it?\nIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of usist true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.",
          "author": "2132156",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "title": "Sony return as new smartphone builder",
          "content": "Why do we use it?\nIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of u",
          "author": "231113",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "title": "Life is Essential",
          "content": "Why do we use it?\nIt is a long established fact that",
          "author": "2132156",
          "id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please add expected output and a description of what issue you're encountering with your existing code - it's not clear what you're asking or what problems you're encountering.

Comment: How about `$data["blogs"][] = $input`?

Comment: That's work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ADyson pointed out, the only thing that needs to change is how you add new data into an array.

```
    //append the input to our array
    $data[] = $input;
```

This will append the new data directly to `$data` array, but you want to append to the associative index `blogs` so you have to specify that.

```
    $data['blogs'][] = $input;
```